# Insert string dumped from a dictionary, which includes utf8 characters, to mysql, in Python

Tags: python, mysql, character-encoding

I know when you want to insert some utf8 characters to mysql, you just encode your characters like this:

```
# ... set the db to utf8-friendly
# ... some connection initialization

stmt = """INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
cursor.execute(stmt, (1001, u"小明".encode("utf8"))
conn.commit()

# ... close connection
```

But if I have a dictionary including utf8 characters and I write the script as the following:

```
mydict = {u"名字": u"小明", "sex": "male"}
mydict_str = json.dumps(mydict)

stmt = """INSERT INTO test (id, params) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
cursor.execute(stmt, (1001, mydict_str))
conn.commit()
```

Then I got this:

```
---- + -----------
 ID  |    params
---- + -----------
1001 | {"\u540d\u5b57": "\u5c0f\u660e", "sex": "male"} # what I want here is {"名字": "小明"...}
```

I tried this but nothing happened, the same record was inserted:

```
mydict = {u"名字".encode("utf8"): u"小明".encode("utf8"), "sex": "male"}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What about `'SET NAMES UTF8'` ? eg. `conn = MySQLdb.connect(charset='utf8', init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')`

Comment: Do you need the `.encode(..)`?

Comment: Does `SELECT HEX(name) FROM test WHERE id = 1001` give you `E5B08FE6988E` for `小明`?  (It should.)

Comment: @MrUpsidown - When working with Chinese, be sure to use `utf8mb4`, not just `utf8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `ensure_ascii=False` when calling `json.dumps()`.

For example,

```
mydict_str = json.dumps(mydict, ensure_ascii=False)
```